# How to organize assembly code?

Tags: assembly, nasm, fasm, yasm

Assembly code tends to be incredibly messy when there are no proper rules for organizing the code. Can anybody suggest some useful techniques for code organization, including macros, procedures, etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use the rules of the [Structured programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structured_programming) - the usual tool for avoiding such problems.